# Duplicate records in SQL except for date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in SQL that makes a distinct of all the records in the table, but there are records that have different dates, I want to keep only those with the last date, because removing the date the data is duplicated.

This is the table I have right now:

| data1 | data2 | data3 | fecDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| renault | megane | diesel | 2008 |
| renault | megane | diesel | 2010 |
| renault | megane | diesel | 2002 |
| ford | focus | gasoline | 2004 |
| ford | focus | gasoline | 2005 |

This is what I want to display:

| data1 | data2 | data3 | fecDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| renault | megane | diesel | 2010 |
| ford | focus | gasoline | 2005 |

I have tried to put MAX(fecDate) as fecDate in the Select but it only takes one record, in the where with a subquery I have not been able to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot the `group by` clause:

```
select max(fecDate) as fecDate, data1,data2,data3 from table_name group by data1, data2, data3
```